# 403 Error: Create & Assign Azure Policy Definition at Management Group Level using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-policy, azure-management-groups

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_management_group" "management_group" {
  display_name = var.management_group_display_name
}

resource "azurerm_policy_definition" "deployment_policy_definition" {
  name                = "resources-in-eastus-policy"
  policy_type         = "Custom"
  mode                = "All"
  display_name        = "Allowed to only deploy in East US location"
  management_group_id = data.azurerm_management_group.management_group.id

  policy_rule = <<POLICY_RULE
    {
    "if": {
      "not": {
        "field": "location",
        "in": "[parameters('allowedLocations')]"
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "audit"
    }
  }
POLICY_RULE

  parameters = <<PARAMETERS
    {
    "allowedLocations": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The list of allowed locations for resources.",
        "displayName": "Allowed locations",
        "strongType": "location"
      }
    }
  }
PARAMETERS
}

resource "azurerm_management_group_policy_assignment" "mngmt_grp_dep_pol_assign" {
  name                 = "assign-pol-to-mgmt-grp"
  policy_definition_id = azurerm_policy_definition.deployment_policy_definition.id
  management_group_id  = data.azurerm_management_group.management_group.id
  parameters           = <<PARAMETERS
{
  "allowedLocations": {
    "value": [ "eastus" ]
  }
}
PARAMETERS
}
```

Error: creating/updating Policy Definition "resources-in-eastus-policy": policy.DefinitionsClient#CreateOrUpdateAtManagementGroup: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client 'live.com#XXX@gmail.com' with object id '0ab7dad7-dba2-46d9-8cc6-878647e9a5cb' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/Microsoft.Management/1/Microsoft.Authorization/resources-in-eastus-policy/write' over scope '/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/1/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."

Azure Roles added for the owner/user of the azure-cli
[image: Azure Roles Assigned To The User]

The ID of the target management group where I am trying to create and assign the policy under the Tenant Root Group is 1

Answer (score 0):

Error:

> The client 'live.com#XXX@gmail.com' with object id
> '0ab7daxxxxxxx-xxxxe9a5cb' does not have authorization to perform
> action
> 'Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/Microsoft.Management/1/Microsoft.Authorization/resources-in-eastus-policy/write

- As the error mentions the client doesn’t have proper RBAC role to perform policy definition creation on management groups.
- Try to assign that ObjectId mentioned in the error , the proper role like `Management Group Contributor` OR `Management Group Reader role`.

> **Note:** ***The principal/user which is deploying ,must have permissions like `Contributor` to create resources at the tenant scope and to assign that permission one must have Owner role***

Also see below table from [management-group-access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/overview#management-group-access) :

> [image]

- From the management group , Go to  Access control (IAM), add your client(user/service principal) as an RBAC role

[image]

or provide role through **`powershell`**:

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -Scope '/' -RoleDefinitionName 'Owner' -ObjectId <objectidofftheclient>
```

Then wait for some time for the role to reflect and then try to create policy assignment to management group:

[image]

Policy assignment made to management group.

[image]

Please make sure if the management group is reflected properly and check the id is correct  in terraform, if it is already created in portal. Else import them using `terraform import` and then perform terraform operations.

Comment: Thank you Kavya for taking time to articulate a very detailed response, but the object ID in reference here does have the RBAC permissions (Management Group Contributor, Owner, Contributor, Resource Policy Contributor, User Access Administrator) you have highlighted. The ID of my mgmt group is 1, which is being correctly read. But still 403. The object ID can perform the required just fine using the portal.

Comment: Azure CLI Details: 

azure-cli                         2.40.0

core                              2.40.0
telemetry                          1.0.8


Dependencies:
msal                            1.18.0b1
azure-mgmt-resource             21.1.0b1

Comment: Please check if you are logged  into correct tenant /subscription  .Try running `az login --subscription`  or check current tenant details.